# Joining tables in SQL if table value is equal to another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables. They all represent a different stage of a process.

Table1:

```
ID   Process1

1    a       
2    b
3    c
4    d
```

Table 2:

```
ID   ID2     Process2
1    50        e
2    51        f
4    52        g
```

Table 3:

```
IDfromPrevious   ID3   Process3
50               500   h
51               501   i
52               502   j
3                503   k
```

I want to create Table 4:

```
ID3  Process1  Process2  Process3
500   a          e           h
501   b          f           i
502   d          g           j
503   c                      k
```

The problem is some item move from process 1 to 3. Other items move from process 1 to 2 to 3. Everything however ends up at Process 3. The item also get assigned a new ID through each process. I am work in ms access 2016.

I don't know where to start with the SQL statement. I've never written if statements in SQL but I want the logic to work something like this:

```
SELECT Table3.ID3, Table1.Process1, Table2.Process2, Table3.Process3
FROM (IF Table1.ID = Table3.IDfromPrevious Then Table1 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.ID = Table3.IDfromPervious ELSE Table2.ID2 = Table3.IDfromPrevious Then Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.ID2 = Table3.IDfromPervious)
```

Comment: There's no conditional execution available in SQL queries.

Comment: is it possible to have an IDfromPrevious  in table3 that is present both in table1 and table2?

Comment: How do you know that `IDFromPrevious` of 3 is from table 1 and not table 2? I would also suggest that you Google "sql trees and hierarchies joe celko". He wrote an entire book on the subject, although you can get enough information to model this data correctly just from some of his news group and forum posts out there.

Comment: Because of the way this item is processed tables 1 and 2 will never have the same ID and ID2. ID has a relationship with IDfromPrevious as well as ID2 has a relationship with IDfromPrevious.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access is only supports a subset of standard ISO SQL. After several attempts it seems this is only possible via a subquery. That subquery can then be outer joined with an `Nz` condition as follows:

```
SELECT    Table3.ID3, Table12.Process1, Table12.Process2, Table3.Process3
FROM       (SELECT    Table2.ID2, Table1.ID, Table1.Process1, Table2.Process2
            FROM      Table1
            LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID = Table1.ID) AS Table12
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.IDfromPrevious =  Nz(Table12.ID2, Table12.ID)
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error. It says: "Syntax error in query expression 'Table3 ON Table3.IDFromPrevious IN (Table1.ID, Table2.ID2)'."

Comment: You'd probalby have to do `LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.IDFromPrevious = Table1.ID OR Table3.IDFromPrevious = Table2.ID2`

Comment: I added that as alternative. MS Access has many limitations compared to standard SQL. Possibly `Nz` will work. Added that as another alternative.

Comment: I've tried all of these. I'm still getting "this JOIN is not supported" error

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I finally had MS Access set up with your data. My updated answer should work. Could you let me know?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
ID INT
,Process1 VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES
(1,'a')
,(2,'b')
,(3,'c')
,(4,'d')

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
ID INT
,ID2 INT
,Process2 VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table2
VALUES
(1,50,'e')
,(2,51,'f')
,(4,52,'g')



DECLARE @Table3 TABLE
(
IDfromPrevious INT
,ID3 INT
,Process3 VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table3
VALUES
(50,500,'h')
,(51,501,'i')
,(52,502,'j')
,(3,503,'k')

SELECT * FROM @Table1
SELECT * FROM @Table2
SELECT * FROM @Table3


SELECT 
ID3
,Process1
,Process2
,Process3
FROM @Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT JOIN @Table3 T3 ON T3.IDfromPrevious IN (T2.ID2,T1.ID)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do it the simple way, join both conditions and then keep the not NULL

```
select t3.ID3, isnull(t1.process1, tx.Process1) Process1, t2.Process2, t3.Process3
from t3
left join t2 on t3.IDfromPrevious = t2.ID2
left join t1 on t2.ID = t1.ID
left join t1 tx on t3.IDfromPrevious = tx.ID
```